# SQL Server Bulk Insert - columns delimited by quotes and containing quotes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I'm trying to import a text file into SQL Server using BULK INSERT. Here's a sample line containing the exception I'm having issues with::

```
"AB123","Sample Data ""B"" Test",7/12/2007,"ABC","More Sample Data"
```

I have a format file that works for the import except for when there are the extra double quotes inside column #2 ("").

```
1       SQLCHAR             0       8       "\",\""     1     Field1                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       7       "\","     2     Field2                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       6       ",\""     3     Field3                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       12      "\",\""     4     Field4 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       24      "\r\n"     5     Field5 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The data is not consistent - sometimes the text fields contain the additional double quotes, sometimes not.

Any ideas or help on how to do this without having to edit the original file? Thank you

Comment: You need regular expressions, which is not available for `BULK INSERT`, AFAIK. My guess is that you trigger the `BULK INSERT` from a command-line environment. If so, you should be able to create a copy of the file, run it through `sed/awk` or any other processor of your choice, before giving it as argument to the insert operation. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I ended up doing is linking the text files to Access, then linking the Access DB to SQL Server, then using SELECT INTO to complete the import process, and this works just fine. Apparently Access has no problem reading files in this format.